# Windows 7 loses static IP on Restart, but not on Shutdown

Tags: windows-7, networking, shutdown

I have a computer that has been configured to use a Static IP, but if the computer is restarted using the option from the Start Menu, it loses this configuration. If the computer is Shutdown, then turned on, the  configuration sticks.

What is the difference between "Restarting" and Shutdown/Power on? I have configured many many computers to use static IPs and have never before run into this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: May have fixed it by disabling the antivirus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by disabling the antivirus program.